# Installing Java on FreeBSD: `sudo pkg install openjdk11-11.0.4+11.1` fails to find package despite being listed in the "FreeBSD Ports Search" page

Tags: software-installation, package-management, freebsd, java, bsd-ports

On the [*FreeBSD Ports Search*](https://www.freebsd.org/ports/index.html) page, I [see results listing](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/ports.cgi?query=OpenJDK&stype=all) an item [`openjdk11-11.0.4+11.1`](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/ports/head/java/openjdk11).

When I try to install that:

```zsh
$ sudo pkg install openjdk11-11.0.4+11.1
```

…I get error saying the package could not be found:

> Updating FreeBSD repository catalogue...
>
> FreeBSD repository is up to date.
>
> All repositories are up to date.
>
> pkg: No packages available to install matching 'openjdk11-11.0.4+11.1' have been found in the repositories

➥ What am I missing here? What is the proper way to install Java/OpenJDK 11 or 12 on FreeBSD 12?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

Use the short general name of the project `openjdk11`, not the long specific package name `openjdk11-11.0.4+11.1`.

```zsh
$ sudo pkg install openjdk11
```

## Use short name of project

Click that link you posted, the listing for item [`openjdk11-11.0.4+11.1`](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/ports/head/java/openjdk11).

[image: screenshot of the detail page for the <code>openjdk11</code> package in the FreeBSD Ports & Packages site.]

On the next displayed page, note the header:

> Index of /head/java/openjdk11

Take that last part as the name of the package to be installed. So here, we want just `openjdk11`.

Install using that short name.

```zsh
$ sudo pkg install openjdk11
```

…and the prompt appears asking to go forward with installation. You will automatically get the latest update to that version of Java. Notice in the listing that web page seen above how both 11.0.3 and an update to 11.0.4 are mentioned.

## Binary package

For a pre-built install of Java simply run:

```
sudo pkg install openjdk12
```

You will then find your OpenJDK installed at `/usr/local/openjdk12/`.

You may then want to set some environment variables to lead to your installation. For example, in my `.zshrc` file to configure zsh I add:

```
 path+=/usr/local/openjdk12/bin
```